# Pinning specific subsection in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, pinning

I'm trying to pin some packages from a specific subsection (gnome in this case) in Debian jessie. For subsection I mean: gnome, admin, x11, etc… This value is showed by apt-cache in the 'Section' field for any package.

There are a lot of example about use apt pinning based on origin (the 'o' parameter), label ('l'), release ('a'), etc... but none of them shows how to pin a subsection.

For reference, this is the most common example:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental
Pin-Priority: 450
```

Some other examples use wildcards on the Package line, but I'm not interested in pinning 'gnome*' packages since there are other packages in the gnome section that doesn't match that expression ([see this link for the list](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/gnome/))

What I'm want is something like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=experimental,x=gnome
Pin-Priority: 450
```

I'm looking for that 'x' parameter which 'filters' by subsection, but I don't know its name or even if it exists. The documentation about apt-pinning, as many of you may already know, it's very imprecise and incomplete.

Comment: `but none of them shows how to pin a subsection` - AFAIK it simply isn't possible.  This is such an obscure thing, you may be better off asking on the official Debian mail lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's (currently) not possible.

You can pin to either package names or anything in the output of `apt-cache policy` (without further parameter), e.g.

```
 600 http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.ch.debian.org
```

So you can pin to the release's origin (o), the archive/suite name (a), the codename (n), the label (l), the component (c) or the origin's hostname. This basically means you can pin per `Packages` list, but not to subsets of packages in one `Packages` list (except for package names of course).